# Mirror an image with stretched pixels arced between

Tags: photoshop-effects

I am looking to replicate the way this photo is edited. I would like to create the effect of having a mirrored image with the pixels stretched between the two sides (with the pixels bent upwards).

Thanks
[image: Example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a potential solution for achieving the effect in your post.

Starting image
[image: Original]

Select and delete any section you don't want in the final image.
[image: Crop]

Duplicate and mirror
[image: Mirror]

Select the pixels on the edge of one side and copy them to a new layer.
[image: Select Edge]

Stretch the line of pixels across the gap.
[image: Stretch]

Go to Edit -> Transform -> Warp and from the drop down menu select Arc Upper.
[image: Warp]

Set the percentage you want those pixels to bend.
[image: Set Bend]

This will be the final result.
[image: Final]

Comment: thank you very much. it's a perfect answer. you're the best! :)